# Number of threads created in the thread pool when using Executors.newCachedThreadPool()

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

How many threads are initially created in the thread pool when using `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` the Javadoc doesn't specify any number is there a guaranteed number that we will always get like 10 initially or something.Docs below:

> newCachedThreadPool public static ExecutorService
>   newCachedThreadPool() Creates a thread pool that creates new threads
>   as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are
>   available. These pools will typically improve the performance of
>   programs that execute many short-lived asynchronous tasks. Calls to
>   execute will reuse previously constructed threads if available. If no
>   existing thread is available, a new thread will be created and added
>   to the pool. Threads that have not been used for sixty seconds are
>   terminated and removed from the cache. Thus, a pool that remains idle
>   for long enough will not consume any resources. Note that pools with
>   similar properties but different details (for example, timeout
>   parameters) may be created using ThreadPoolExecutor constructors.
>   Returns: the newly created thread pool

Comment: _If no existing thread is available, a new thread will be created and added to the pool._

Comment: Im staying on creation of the pool how many threads are initially created 0, 1, 10, not guaranteed to be any integer? So if you think about Arraylist or something it initialized with 10 elements and if it needs to grow it will do so later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `0`.

You can find in [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java?av=f#215) that right after `ThreadPoolExecutor` [creation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#1296) there is [no workers spawned](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#465).